# How i can put more information in the view? Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know this is probably a stupid question.
I would want to know what I should do and how should I go ahead if I want to write or put information in the view that i can't see in the activity.xml in Eclipse.
Shall I use a scrollBar? If yes then what should i do for that?

Comment: Do you mean 'how do I programmatically add items to a view' or 'how do I let the user scroll the view'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a `<ScrollView>`, [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/) is a good exemple.

Comment: Yes, but then how i can write where i can't see in eclipse activity.xml?

Comment: in eclipse you can see everything. It is just on the screen of the phone or the emulator, or the graphical-layout (in which you use drag and drop for adding elements) that you can see everything.

So open the code (*.xml) and put what ever you want into the <ScrollView>  and when you will run the application, you will have to scroll to see everything